# Credentials using Invoke-Sqlcmd against sql azure

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I'm attempting to run a powershell build script against a sql azure database but receiving `Login failed for user 'X'`.

I'm fairly convinced the credentials are correct as they were taken straight from the live application config.

This is the command I'm using:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "Build.sql" -ServerInstance $server -Database $database `
              -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -OutputSqlErrors $false  `
              -Username $username -Password $password -EncryptConnection
```

I had this working with sqlcmd in a batch file so I'm wondering if it's got anything to do with the way the credentials are being sent, trusted_connection=false doesn't appear to be an option I can try.

Answer (score 2):

When connecting to SQL Azure the login name must be of the form `user@server`. So if you created an user 'foo' and a server 'bar', the login must be `foo@bar`. See [Managing Databases and Logins in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins):

> Because some tools implement tabular data stream (TDS) differently, you may need to append the Azure SQL Database server name to the login in the connection string using the `<login>@<server>` notation. In these cases, separate the login and Azure SQL Database server name with the `@` symbol. For example, if your login was named `login1` and the fully qualified name of your Azure SQL Database server is `servername.database.windows.net`, the username parameter of your connection string should be: `login1@servername`.

[CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) also explains this:

> In some methods of connecting to SQL Database, such as sqlcmd, you must append the SQL Database server name to the login name in the connection string by using the `<login>@<server>` notation. For example, if your login is `login1` and the fully qualified name of the SQL Database server is `servername.database.windows.net`, the username parameter of the connection string should be `login1@servername`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and url, although I've triple checked that.  I think I might have to try and roll a different command to see if it's that.  Something tells me its the authentication mode but example on the net suggest I'm doing it correctly.  I even logged into to the online management with the same details :(

Answer (score 2):

It could be the password contains a few special characters that Azure/Invoke-sqlcmd does not handle (such as dollar, single or double quote, parentheses).  I tried using the Azure interface and surrounding the password with single-quotes (we had a dollar-sign in the password), but that did not work.  So, we simply removed the special character and now it is OK.  see: [Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd Login Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335651/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-login-failed)
and 
https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/08/09/vsts-azure-sql-database-deployment-task-keeps-failing-with-error-login-failed-for-user/